# How to insert a flag at the end of the execution command line using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following files:

```
main.cpp
libgamepad\libgamepad.so
CMakeLists.txt
```

I can build the file using the following command:

```
c++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -L/projectDir/libgamepad -lgamepad -g
```

Below is the CMakeLists.txt content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(DD2)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(DD2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libgamepad -lgamepad")
```

And I build the project with cmake the command which get executed is:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -g   -L/projectDir/libgamepad -lgamepad CMakeFiles/DD2.dir/main.cpp.o  -o DD2
```

And it results in an error. I want to know if there is any way I can insert the two arguments (`-L/projectDir/libgamepad -lgamepad`) at the end of the execution command so the below command will be issued:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -g   CMakeFiles/DD2.dir/main.cpp.o -L/projectDir/libgamepad -lgamepad -o DD2
```

Comment: Why don't you specify lgamepad as a dependency in cmake? Than CMake will make sure correct placement is achieved.

Comment: @SergeyA can you explain more on how I can do that?